# Remote connection between Raspberry pi and other computer through python over internet on real time

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi, real-time, remote-connection

I want a help in robotics stuff..
My Question is ... :

How to connect my robotic car ( car is  having raspberry pi as controller) with my computer via internet .. so the I can control the car from my computer's keybord..

Previously i was using VNC and made a python tkinter  script (stored at raspberry pi) and by the help of vnc i control the car but it was not good ..

Most of the time the when i press the key,  function works after sometime and worst thing was that it stores all the commands in a queue or buffer ..

So realtime operation was not happenping ( like: if i press forward arrow key for 2 seconds, it evoked moveForward() 20 times which is equal to 2 meters forward move and takes 4 seconds to travel .. BUT after that if i press right arrow key then it evokes moveRight() .. the worst part is it will execute after finishing the moveForward() stored in a queue i.e after 4 seconds .. and not on real time)

Is there any way to control/give command to raspberry pi on real time and not in a queue manner via socketing or other thing ?
note : i have a static ip address with specific port open and it has to be done over internet.

Answer (score 0):

The appearance of your car might mainly relate to the whole system response time. The Raspberry Pi may be not fast enough. If there is no necessary, analog signal may on real time.

Comment: Problem is execution in functions in real time and function is evoked over internet. Every command i use to give to the system ... raspberry pi store them in a queue and because of this system is not realtime.. BUT I will see analog fashion as suggested by you .. Thank you :-)